# Pattern matching character strings when everything but the last two elements of the character are the same

Tags: r

I have the following vector.

```
column_names <- c("6Li", "7Li", "10B", "11B", "7Li.1",
                  "205Pb", "206Pb", "207Pb", "238U",
                  "206Pb.1", "238U.1")
```

Notice that some of the values are just duplicates with a ".1" stuck at the end. I want to index out all of these character strings along with their corresponding character strings that match such that only the following are returned.

```
#[1] "7Li"     "7Li.1"   "206Pb"   "238U"    "206Pb.1" "238U.1"
```

Assume you don't know the index positions and so you cannot simply index these values out as follows `column_names[c(2,5,7,9,10,11)]`. How can I use pattern matching to extract these values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is likely a more elegant solution, but in base R you cold try a combination of `grep`/`gsub` and `paste`:

```
idx <- grep(paste(gsub("\\.1", "", column_names[grep("\\.1", column_names)]), collapse = "|"), column_names)
# [1]  2  5  7  9 10 11

column_names[idx]
# [1] "7Li"     "7Li.1"   "206Pb"   "238U"    "206Pb.1" "238U.1"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `gsub()` and `duplicated()` to find values with repeated stems:

```
column_stems <- gsub("\\.1", "", column_names)

dup_idx <- duplicated(column_stems) | duplicated(column_stems, fromLast = TRUE)

column_names[dup_idx]
# "7Li"     "7Li.1"   "206Pb"   "238U"    "206Pb.1" "238U.1"
```

To also find instances ending with `.2`, `.3`, etc., use `"\\.\\d+"` instead of `"\\.1"` in `gsub()`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `stringr`:

```r
library(stringr)

idx <- str_extract(column_names, ".*(?=\\.1)")

column_names[str_detect(column_names, paste(idx[!is.na(idx)], collapse = "|"))]
```

This returns

```r
#> [1] "7Li"     "7Li.1"   "206Pb"   "238U"    "206Pb.1" "238U.1"
```